# Sample size for GLM with quasi-binomial distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, sampling, sample-size, percentage

My data represent percentages of total enzyme that is catalytically active. Something like relative units to total amount. Data are infiltrated with zeros (i.e. no activity detected)

I have 4 groups, each of 6 patients. (i.e. so total 24 observations with percentage of active enzymes)

I figure out that for percentage data I can use GLM with quasibinomial distribution and correct the analysis for age , sex etc.

I am worried about small sample size or only 6 observations per group?

Is it ok to use GLM with quasibinomial in this case?

Thanks

Comment: The general theory is you should have no less than 30-samples to approximate normal and at least 5 of each category, The trick here, you have 4-groups which are a category of sorts (depending on how sampled) and also, age and sex. You need to be sure the minimums are met for EACH category, though not across categories (meaning you do not need 5 males who are 88-years-old, just 5 males and 5-88-year olds (or bins of ages))

Comment: Does not mean you cannot analyze it, but will affect confidence and how aggressively you and assert inference from it

Answer (score 0):

> I am worried about small sample size or only 6 observations per group?
> Is it ok to use GLM with quasibinomial in this case?

You can fit a model with 6 observations per group but the quality of the inference may be effected.  This will depend on the differences between groups (bigger differences will be easier to detect, smaller ones will be harder).

Whether or not it is "OK" is largely dependent on the context, which is missing from the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My study design includes: 4 groups of 6 observations per each group. In brief, I have short and long cancer survival group, each time 6 control “surrounding lung “tissues and 6 lung tumor tissues. (in total 24 different samples)

My first question would be   tumor vs. control changes in both groups?
My second question: long versus short survival changes based on  tumor and “surrounding/ control “ tissue?

Comment: I did binary GLM and then posthoc correction for pairwise comparisons.

My data are independent numerical variables –quantitative measure of metabolic enzymes. The enzymes have two quantitative data: the abundances (i.e. my data matrix 1) and functional activities (my data matrix 2).

So for the first data set I am using linear model ( lm) . abundance data are normally distributed,
For the second data I am using GLM with quaibinominal ditribution, since the activity data are like percentages of total enzyme form (e.g. 0, 0.2, 0.35, 0.75, 0.05..)

Comment: What would be alternative to check for differential changes per each enzyme?
ANOVA test for abundance data1   and  Kruskal-Wallis test for activity data2?
But then, how to correct for common confounders (age, sex...)?

Comment: @Princ_078 This is an altogether separate question, and I think you'd be better off making a different post concerning your design rather than relying on me alone to answer this.